# Checkbox variable causing error when NOT submitted in form PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, checkbox

I have a PHP variable $admin which corresponds to a checkbox. When the form is submitted with the checkbox ticked, the value is passed (set as 1) and everything is fine, however if it's not ticked the variable causes an undefined index error:

Notice: Undefined index: admin in C:...\admin.php

This is the php section of the form that queries the db:

```
  if($row == 1)
    {
        echo '<div id="errormsg">This username is already taken</div>';
    }
    else

    {
    $add = mysqli_query($dbcon, "INSERT INTO users (id, firstname, lastname, username, password, admin) VALUES
    (null, '$fname', '$lname', '$user', '$pass', '$admin') ") or die ("Can't insert data");
    echo '<div id="create-success">Successfully added user!</div>';
    }
```

And the HTML form:

```
  <form action="admin.php" method="post" onSubmit="return validate(this)">
<fieldset>
    <label class="reg">Username *</label> <input type="text" name="user" /><br />
    <label class="reg">Password *</label> <input type="password" name="pass" /><br />
    <label class="reg">Repeat Password *</label> <input type="password" name="rpass" /><br />
    <label class="reg">First name:</label> <input type="text" name="fname" /><br />
    <label class="reg">Last name:</label> <input type="text" name="lname" /><br />
    <label class="reg">Admin?:</label> <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="admin" /><br/>
</fieldset>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create User" />
</form>
```

Ha anyone any ideas why NOT checking the box causes an error specific to the $admin variable?

Comment: I'm guessing that when the box is not checked it's sending no or NULL value.  You should intercept the POST first, set the variable manually yourself.  That way you know it has a valid value.

Comment: You should show the portion of your script that deals with handling values in `$_POST`. in all likelihood, this is where your problem lies. You may also consider not telling the user if a username has already been taken.  This is considered bad practice from a security standpoint.

Comment: The POST's are simply set as $admin = $_POST['admin']; etc

Answer (score 4):

Checkboxes are only actually passed to the script if they are checked.

So you need to check for there existance in your php code, something like this:

```
if ( $_POST && isset( $_POST['admin'] ) {
    $admin = $_POST['admin'];
} else {
    $admin = 0;
}
```

EDIT:

In your script I would do this

```
if($row == 1) {
    echo '<div id="errormsg">This username is already taken</div>';
} else {
    $admin = ( $_POST && isset( $_POST['admin'] ) ? $_POST['admin'] : 0;
    $add = mysqli_query($dbcon, "INSERT INTO users 
               (id, firstname, lastname, username, password, admin) 
         VALUES(null, '$fname', '$lname', '$user', '$pass', '$admin') ") or die ("Can't insert data");
    echo '<div id="create-success">Successfully added user!</div>';
}
```

Comment: I thought it could be something to do with that. Where would that code fit into my script?

Comment: Anywhere before you try use the `$admin` variable

Comment: I was after something like this but its not stopped the error unfortunately

Comment: What is the exact error message and show the line that is it occuring on

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to check is that admin variable in Post Array. Please check code.

```
<?php
if($row == 1)
{
 echo '<div id="errormsg">This username is already taken</div>';
}
else
{
// check is exist in post array
$isAdminCheck = (isset($_POST['admin']) && $_POST['admin'] == 1 )? $_POST['admin']:0;

$add = mysqli_query($dbcon, "INSERT INTO users (id, firstname, lastname, username,   password, admin) VALUES    (null, '$fname', '$lname', '$user', '$pass', '$isAdminCheck') ") or die ("Can't insert data");
echo '<div id="create-success">Successfully added user!</div>';
}
?>
```